# Symfony + RestBundle: how to set only "versioning url"?

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am building the backend of an app and for the REST side I use FOSRestBundle. Now I have created an Action like this:

```
/ **
* @Get ("/path/my")
* /
getUserDataAction public function ()
{
...
}
```

and if I exec "php app / debug console: router" I get two entries:

```
app_myapp_getuserdata GET ANY ANY /path/my
api_myapp_get_user_data GET ANY ANY /api/v1/path/my.{_format}
```

How do I exclude the first and leave only the /api/v1 (versioning) available? Why the first is been created?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation of versioning](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html#how-to-match-a-specific-version-in-my-routing):

```php
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Version;

/**
 * @Version("v2")
 *
 * or if you support multiple versions in this controller
 * @Version({"v1", "v2"})
 */
class MyController
{
}
```

and

```yml
# config.yml
fos_rest:
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        default_version: 1.0
```

Comment: do you have to add {version} in routing config as well some where?